# Pyarmor does not recursively generate obfuscated files

Tags: pyarmor

I have been unable to get pyarmor to recursively obfuscate files with even the simplest case. Here, I have two files, main.py and foo.py.
The contents of main.py are:

```
import foo

foo.test()
```

and the contents of foo.py are:

```
def test():
    print('test')
```

When I try and recursively generate the obfuscated files from main.py I get the following

```
C:\Code\amatbb.amat.com\ssd_workbench\PyarmorTest>pyarmor gen -r main.py
INFO     Python 3.8.10
INFO     Pyarmor 8.0.19 (basic), 004046, TBD
INFO     search inputs ...
INFO     find script main.py
INFO     find 1 top resources
INFO     start to generate runtime files
INFO     target platforms {'windows.amd64'}
INFO     write dist\pyarmor_runtime_004046\pyarmor_runtime.pyd
INFO     patch runtime file
INFO     generate runtime files OK
INFO     start to obfuscate scripts
INFO     process resource "main"
INFO     obfuscating file main.py
INFO     write dist\main.py
INFO     obfuscate scripts OK
```

Here this doesnt obfuscate foo, even though it is imported in main.py. When trying to run the obfuscated main.py, I get the expected following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<dist/main.py>", line 3, in <module>
  File "<main>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

This seems like the most trivial example, so I suspect I am missing something obvious, however Im at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [text](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have tried recursive generating the simplest case, but it only seems to obfuscate the top level file

Comment: Did you include `foo.py` when you distributed this?

Comment: Im not sure what is meant by distributing it. Im not packing it, just obfuscating it. I import it in my main file, but dont reference it anywhere else. Am I missing something?

Comment: And why didn't you do `pyarmor gen main.py foo.py`?

Comment: Because I am trying to use the recursion feature of pyarmor, and specifying them manually is not feasible for my true use case. This is an example where I am trying to demonstrate the problem, but in reality I have a main file which imports 20+ custom libraries that change arbitrarily. I would like to have a simple command that automatically obfuscated the whole project, without manually needing to manually specify them. This was a feature advertised by pyarmor (which I paid for), so I expected it to work, https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyarmor/latest/pyarmor.pdf page 9.

Comment: If you paid for support, then you should ask them.  Does it work if you do `cd dist` / `python main.py`?  It may be as simple as a path issue.